# Can't get "a user connected" feedback from Socket.IO

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

Im trying to connect my iOS app in Xcode to my Node server using Socket.io but I am not getting any feedback from Socket.io. This is what my **ViewController.swift** consist of:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

This is what my **SocketIOManager.swift** file consists of:

```
import UIKit

  class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
  static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000")! as URL)

override init() {
    super.init()
}

func establishConnection() {
    socket.connect()
}

func closeConnection() {
    socket.disconnect()
}

}
```

**My AppDelegate:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.closeConnection()

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()

}
```

And finally my **Server Side**:

```
var app = require ('http').createServer();

app.listen(3000) 

  //Run Server
  var io = require('socket.io')(app);{
  console.log('Listening on *:3000');
  };

io.on('connection', function(socket){
 console.log('a user connected');
 socket.on('disconnect', function(){
 console.log('user disconnected');
   });
 });
```

When I start my server I get `Listening on *:3000`. However when starting the iphone simulator in XCode, I'm then supposed get `a user connected` in terminal but I get no feedback. No **`a user connected`** no **`Errors`** no nothing at all. I provided all my files because I am at lost about what and where the problem is. Can someone help me.